# Creating a support Rogue

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I'm a DM. For the next planned campaign with my regular group, we've agreed to go for an All-Rogue campaign, that is to say, each player plays a Rogue. No hybrid, no multiclassing. Anything else is green-lit (although if possible, I'd like to shy away from content from Dark Sun, Eberron or Forgotten Realms on this one).

One of the players asked if it was possible to create a healer, as a Rogue. I can improvise any monster on the spot, but I'm rubbish at making characters. I've tinkered away in the character builder, and came up with something of a support rogue with a lot of potions. I've also focused mobility and Wisdom (the Heal modifier), hopefully making a Rogue that can shift around the battleground as a potion/first aid dispenser.

My question is, **Is there a better approach, and if not, did I do it right?**

Below are the stats of what I came up with:

---

*Characters start at Level 5, and can expect to end the campaign at Level 11 at minima (13 at most). They also start with a bit more money than they normally would; around 2,000 gp.*

STR: 14
CON: 10
DEX: 16
INT: 10
WIS: 18
CHA: 14
Class: Rogue
Rogue Tactics option: Artful Dodger
Race: Elf for the bonus in Dex *and* Wis
Theme: Alchemist (free item-making feat, allows to make herbal poultices for free early)
Background: Surgeon; Bonus: can train in Heal
Trained in: Acrobatics, Athletics, Dungeoneering, and Heal
Feats:

- L1: Herbalist (for the potions at L5)
- L2: Skill Focus (Heal)
- L4: Combat Medic

Chosen powers:

- At-Wills

  - Acrobatic Strike
  - Palming Strike
- L2 Utility

  - Healer's Gift (Skill Power)

Magic items:

- Cloak of Chirurgeon +1
- Goggles of Aura Sight

Comment: “Don't do that” often makes for bad answers and worse comments, so those comments have been removed. People can have fun how they like.

Comment: Is the 2000gp in addition to the L4, L5, and L6 items or not? Since standard magic item load out is an item of Level -1, Level, and Level +1, plus gold equal to a Level -1 item (in this case 1000gp)

Comment: @diego It is in addition, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will start by saying that Rogues are pretty bad when it comes to healing, and other leaderish things. They just aren't designed for it and thus don't really have support. I'll do my best to make something that will be passable however.

First, we want to avoid the Rogue from using Standard actions to heal if we can help it. This means either after combat healing or minor actions in combat. Because of this we are only going to get the bonus to the Heal skill up to +12. This is enough if needed in combat to auto-succeed on granting a second wind, and only need a 3+ to grant a save or stabilize the dying.

Second, an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure. For this reason everyone in the party should have several healing potions, and ideally a way to draw them without using an action (like the feat Quick Draw, or item Battle Harness). Also Lifestealer Weapons might not be a bad idea.

As for your character build, there are a few things I would change.

- Change your Rogue Tactics Option to Cunning Sneak. This is the one option that doesn't have an ability score requirement that you don't want to have to meet.
- Race doesn't really matter as long as they get Dex/Wis as the stat bonuses, I prefer Thri-Kreen for the minor action attack, but this character may need its minor actions more than most rogues.
- For your stats I would use either 10/16/16/8/14/10 or 10/13/18/8/13/10 before racial bonuses. Then at 4 and 8 raise Dex and either Wis or Con. (Also if you use the first array you could also use any Dex/Con races [just switch the Con and Wis scores], that would allow for Revenant or Half-Orc)
- For the U2 power I would pick Iron Resurgence, it is a minor action and it prevents you or your ally from falling in the first place. All of the At-will, encounter, and Daily powers don't really effect how good you are at leading so just pick normal good ones like Low Slash.

  - For feats I would not take Skill focus and instead take Light Blade Expertise.
- For items I would take

  - L4: Battle Harness (Quick Draw plus Initiative bonus is very helpful)
  - L5: Amulet of Life (Extra healing once per encounter is nice)
  - L6: Either a Magic Dagger, or downgrade the slot to a Lifestealer Dagger
  - 520gp: Belt of Vigor (Every little bit helps)
  - 680gp: Battle Standard of Healing (This restricts your teams mobility somewhat, but again every little bit helps)

Overall this isn't going to be a good Leader, but it will be better than the average Rogue.

Also one other note from your build, bonuses of the the same type don't stack. So the +2 Feat bonus from Combat Medic doesn't do anything (or the Skill focus only gives a +1 depending on how you want to look at it). Similarly the item bonus from the cloak does nothing when the goggles have a +2 item bonus.